# std::function vs. standard functions

Tags: c++, std, c++17

I was playing with *function pointers* vs. *std::function*
and came across the following problem.

Let's consider the folowing code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>

// g++ -std=c++17 SF.C -o SF
// clang++ -std=c++17 SF.C -o SF

int main()
{
    typedef double (*TpFunctionPointer)(double) ;

    TpFunctionPointer pf1 = sin;                     // o.k.
    TpFunctionPointer pf2 = std::sin;                // o.k
    TpFunctionPointer pf3 = std::riemann_zeta;       // o.k

    std::function< double(double) > sf1( sin );                // o.k
    std::function< double(double) > sf2( std::sin );           // fails
    std::function< double(double) > sf3( std::riemann_zeta );  // fails
}
```

Compiling with `g++ v8.2` or `clang v7.0` works fine for the function pointer pf1, pf2, pf3, and for sf1. 
However for sf2 and sf3 I get a rather long error messages, e.g.:

```
SF.C:17:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::function<double(double)>::function(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
  std::function< double(double)> sf2( std::sin );           // fails
```

Is this intended behavior?
Shouldn't `sf2` and `sf3` be fine?

Comment: Actually, even the first one fails for me (hence not an answer for now + what LRIO said)

Comment: funny that this is very much related to a question asked just a couple of seconds ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54182502/call-a-functor-with-a-specific-function-from-an-overload-set

Comment: The difference is that `std::function`'s constructor is templated, so the compiler has no context to deduce an overload from.

Comment: Even more fun is that `double (*pf4)(double) = static_cast<float (*)(float)>(std::sin);` doesn't compile, but `std::function<double(double)> sf4 (static_cast<float (*)(float)>(std::sin)); ` does.

Comment: @molbdnilo Off the top of my head I can't remember how well-defined that is. My gut tells me this is a case of "compiles but isn't legal" but I'd almost put money on it being esoterically correct. Either way a good reason not to use it IMO!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I think it compiles because `std::function` will perform the necessary conversions (from `double` to `float` and back). It's pretty clear why it's legal, but you of course lose accuracy. Mind you, that can be intentional (if you don't need that accuracy).

Comment: @MSalters Hopefully that is the case, rather than a silent (and invalid) fptr cast

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, the cast from overload set to function pointer is basic overload resolution. That's not the risky part. As for the second part (inside `std::function`), that needs to treat the function pointer as a callable object. `std::function<double(double)>` can't just cast a callable object to `double(*) (double)`, e.g. capturing lambda's or any other stateful object can't be cast like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are [multiple overloads of the `<cmath>` `std::sin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sin) (there's [a template version in `<complex>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/sin), but that's not what you want), and the compiler doesn't know which one you want, despite the fact that only one will successfully bind to your `std::function` type! C++ doesn't do lookup backwards in that sense…

…except when it does! An exception is [`static_cast` on a function pointer type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14279874/560648), which is exactly what you need here:

```
std::function<double(double)> sf2(static_cast<double(*)(double)>(&std::sin));
```

There's an example of this on [the `static_cast` cppreference documentation page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast).

Some potential improvements over this general solution (thanks to Nathan and MSalters):

```
std::function<double(double)> sf2(static_cast<TpFunctionPointer>(&std::sin))
```

or

```
std::function<double(double)> sf2([](double val){ return std::sin(val); });
```

Comment: Could also use `[](double val){return std::sin(val);}` if you don't want to remember the function pointer syntax.

Comment: Suggestion: the solution might be more readable using the typedef from the question: `std::function<double(double)> sf2(static_cast<TpFunctionPointer>(&std::sin))`

Comment: @MSalters As is that!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I understand that I can work around the problem with lambdas or casts. The problem with lambdas is, that you actually hide a simple assignement in a lengthy piece of code.  Also the casts make the code less readable.I actually want to the three argument special functions like assoc_laguerre or assoc_legendre which makes these solutions even less readable.  Therefore my question, wether this behavior is intentional by the standard and has some purpose, or just happens with both implementatations, g++ and clang++.

Comment: @Peter This is all standard. I'm not quite prepared to say that it "has some purpose", except that the alternative would require a substantial hack to the lookup rules, and having that on `static_cast` is messy enough.

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit: o.k., so this just happened during the evolution of C++. I think I'll switch my implementation from std::function  to plain function pointers to make the code more readable, although I intended it the other way. Again thanks.